# Error: /home/ec2-user/mongod does not exist. when running command SUDO FOREVER START MONGOD

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, putty, forever

I am getting this error when I run command `sudo forever start mongod`

```
[root@ip-1**-3*-**-5* ec2-user]# sudo forever mongod start
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /home/ec2-user/mongod does not exist.
```

but normally when I run `mongod` or `sudo mongod` it just works fine. help me whats the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify OS Name, OS version, MongoDB version so that we can easy help you. I hope you are using Amazon Linux so you need to use `systemctl` start/stop `mongodb`, following command to enable and start

```
sudo su
chkconfig mongod on
sudo service mongod start
```

and to stop

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

Please have a look [MongoDB Amazon Linux Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/)

Comment: Amazon Linux latest realease, mongodb v3.0.12. and when i am running systemctl start mongod.service. it can not find the command systemctl. can you tell me when we run 'mongod' command then which file gets executed

Comment: You may use ` which mongod` command to know which file executed when you run `mongod` command

Comment: which mongod is returning usr/bin/mongod so I navigate to the folder usr/bin and then run 'forever start mongod'. this time the command executed successfully but the mongod server doesn't start. when I ran 'forever list' it shows the process but under uptime it shows STOPPED when I looked into log file I found following error.

Comment: /usr/bin/mongod:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ^?ELF^B^A^A^C
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:511:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:159:18)
    at node.js:444:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1

Comment: I have updated command in answer. Please do not use `forever` command to run mongodb. You may use `forever` for `node.js` application only

Comment: It didn't work for me because it start the service but when I try to access the data from it through Parse Dashboard it didn't connect. I don't why I think it didn't fully start the service.

Comment: are you able to access `mongo` from command line like mongo shell command `show dbs` ? I mean you are able to access from mongo shell or not?

Comment: no not all. I have 3 dbs in my mongo instance but when I run through 'sudo service mongod start' method 'show dbs' command show only one db which is default db local

Comment: @NaveenSingh that means mongodb running fine otherwise you can not access via mongo shell. You need to check you program rather than starting mongodb again and again

Comment: If `show dbs` isn't showing all the DBs then it's a path issue, where `mongod` didn't start with the correct DB location path.

Comment: But @ArifKhan when I run simply 'mongod' in the terminal and the process starts normally. at that time I am able to access my all dbs normally by shell or dashboard. But when I run through your method I am not able to access the database in either way. It means Mongo Is installed and configure correctly and when I am running 'sudo service mongod start' there is some problem in starting the mongodb service by it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Same reply to you @MarkB.

Comment: @MarkB , I think when I simply run 'mongod' mongodb service is starting and if I am not worng when I run 'sudo service mongod start' it is starting as a service daemon to the system so that it can start with the system start and run always. so if 'mongod' command is working fine then there is no problem with the db location path.